# Parse JSON data with Swift, AlamoFire and SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

As a Swift newcomer, I am very confused about how to parse some JSON data obtained from an API.  I am able to get the JSON data from the api using an alamofire request.  At this point, I think I have an NSDictionary object, JSON as print(JSON) logs to console a good deal of JSON.

```
if let result = response.result.value {
                            let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
                           print("this is what JSON is")
                            print(JSON)
```

My question is, first, is JSON in fact an NSDictionary.  Second, how would I access a value in the JSON.  Do I need to first convert this to a data object.  Or how do I get at the nested data.

For example, let's say the JSON looks like this:

```
 {
   "contact": {
   "first": "Bob",
   "second":"Jones"
    }
 }
```

I came across this code on SO:

```
 let data = JSON(data: JSON)
 print("data\(data["contact"]["first"])")
```

But it throws an error.  I have swiftyJSON installed but happy for solution with or without it.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-handling

Comment: I would recomend using codable, that way you don`t need SwiftyJson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try

```
if let result = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
   if let contact = result["contact"] as? [String:Any] {
      if let first = contact["first"] as?  String {
           print(first)
     }
   }
}
```

also this

```
let data = JSON(data: JSON)
```

gives error because parameter should be of type `Data` not `Dictionary`

I would prefer to return Data from **Alamofire** request and use `Decodable` to parse it and convert to required model

Comment: I don't have decodable because I have an older version of Xcode and hence swift 3.  Does your approach use swiftyJSON or is it just using  swift.

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS!

```
     if let data = response.data {
            let jsonData = JSON(data: data)
            print("data : \(jsonData["contact"]["first"].string)")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift4 introduce amazing Codable protocol.

Using Codable, we can model JSONObject or PropertyList file into equivalent Struct or Classes by writing very few lines of code.

There are many online tool available which creates model class from you JSON
(http://www.json4swift.com/)

Example

```html
  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  let parsedObject = try decoder.decode(Class.self, from: data)
```

You can find detail at below link:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types